# Cucumber: the same background in many of features

Tags: java, cucumber

I have a lot of features (separate *.feature files) with the same background for example:
Test1.feature:

```
Feature: Multiple site support

Background: 
 Given a global administrator named "Greg"
 And a blog named "Greg's anti-tax rants"
 And a customer named "Dr. Bill"
 And a blog named "Expensive Therapy" owned by "Dr. Bill"

Scenario: Dr.Greg posts to his own blog
 Given I am logged in as Dr.Greg
 When I try to post to "Some" im my blog
 Then I should see "Some articles."
```

Test2.feature:

```
Feature: One site support

Background: 
 Given a global administrator named "Greg"
 And a blog named "Greg's anti-tax rants"
 And a customer named "Dr. Bill"
 And a blog named "Expensive Therapy" owned by "Dr. Bill"

Scenario: Greg posts to a client's blog
 Given I am logged in as Greg
 When I try to post to "Expensive Therapy"
 Then I should see "Your article was published.
```

Test3.feature:

```
Feature: Other site support

Background: 
 Given a global administrator named "Greg"
 And a blog named "Greg's anti-tax rants"
 And a customer named "Dr. Bill"
 And a blog named "Expensive Therapy" owned by "Dr. Bill"
...
```

Multiple different feature files use the same backgroud steps, can i make them in a one file and include them in different scenario?
Or is there a better practice for avoiding duplicate the same steps in some features?

Comment: Posted an answer. Please let me know your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@Before` hook.

`@Before` - Execute method before each scenario.

```
    @Before 
     Given a global administrator named "Greg"
     And a blog named "Greg's anti-tax rants"
     And a customer named "Dr. Bill"
     And a blog named "Expensive Therapy" owned by "Dr. Bill"
    
    Scenario: Dr.Greg posts to his own blog
     Given I am logged in as Dr.Greg
     When I try to post to "Some" im my blog
     Then I should see "Some articles."

    Scenario: Greg posts to a client's blog
     Given I am logged in as Greg
     When I try to post to "Expensive Therapy"
     Then I should see "Your article was published.
     ...
```